# Cloud Functions: check if document exists always return exists

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm checking if a document exists by using this cloud function (Typescript).
The problem: the doc doens't exits and it returns exists....

Thank you very much for the help and effort!

```
export const repeat2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  console.log(data.message);
  console.log(data.count);

  const getDocument = admin.firestore().collection('key').doc(data.message).get();

        if(getDocument != null) {
          console.log('EXISTS');
        }

        else {console.log("doens't exist");}

    return {
        repeat_message: data.message,
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`get()` returns a Promise, not the actual document. Also, you need to use `.exists` on the resolved value; check [the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#get_a_document):

```js
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to check if is a column in your document is like this:

```js
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if ('ColumnNAME' in doc.data()) {
        //If exists Do somenthing
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such column in the document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```